# Call CSS3 hover effects with javascript mouseover event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I evoke CSS3 anmation through a javascript mouseover event rather than CSS mouseover `:hover` event?

```
$(.panel').on('mouseover', function{ 
                                      //foo 
                                   });
```

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/bpmUn/) of animation on CSS mouseover

Comment: Should say, good animation, but sadly this is down voted

Comment: that is one good lookin animation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution is to change the css so that it uses an additional class instead of `:hover`:

```
.animation.active {
    background:transparent;
}
.animation.active span {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(52.5deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(52.5deg);
    rotation:52.5deg;
    -webkit-transform:translate(1em, 0);
    -moz-transform:translate(1em, 0);
    translate(1em, 0);
}
```

and then you can toggle the class via jQuery:

```
$('button.toggle').on('click', function() {
  $('a.animation').toggleClass('active');
});
```

### [**Demo on JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bpmUn/4/)

Comment: I got a feeling this answer is going to win :)

Comment: What was good about your question: you provided a fiddle! What was bad: You didn't explain well what you have tried so far and what's the  desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you should simply change CSS of that object manually:

```
$('button').on('click', function{
 $('.animation:hover span').css('webkit-transform:rotate(52.5deg);'+
    '-moz-transform:rotate(52.5deg);'+
    'rotation:52.5deg;'+
    '-webkit-transform:translate(1em, 0);'+
    '-moz-transform:translate(1em, 0);'+
    'translate(1em, 0);');'

});
```

Comment: Well, if you can make a fiddle with jQuery's `$().ready(function () {});` function in it (which I can't figure out how to do), I might give it a try.